# How do we measure $i[\hat\phi(x),\hat\phi(y)]$ in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, specific-reference, measurements, operators

What operational procedure is required to measure $i[\hat\phi(x),\hat\phi(y)]$ in an interacting (or non-interacting) QFT? [assume smearing by test-functions, or give an answer in Fourier space, for $i\bigl[\widetilde{\hat\phi}(k),\widetilde{\hat\phi}(k')\bigr]$, to your taste; give electromagnetic field indices to $\hat\phi(x)$ and transpose the question to QED if the scalar field case seems unreal in an essential way].

In a non-interacting QFT, $i[\hat\phi(x),\hat\phi(y)]$ is a c-number, but in an interacting QFT it may presumably be an observable independent of $\hat\phi(x)$ and $\hat\phi(y)$. How do we measure it, however? If we cannot measure it, is it effectively chosen by convention?

An answer that describes the (operational) difference between $A=\hat\phi(x_1)...\hat\phi(x_i)\hat\phi(x_{i+1})...\hat\phi(x_n)$ and $B=\hat\phi(x_1)...\hat\phi(x_{i+1})\hat\phi(x_i)...\hat\phi(x_n)$ might be equally good (though $A^\dagger\not=A$ and $B^\dagger\not=B$).

As always, a reference would be good.

EDIT: Following Luboš' answer, and more particularly his comments, for which again thanks, $i[\hat\phi(x),\hat\phi(y)]$ is zero if $x-y$ is space-like, both in non-interacting and interacting quantum fields. If a quantum field $\hat\phi(x)$ is the basis for an empirically adequate quantum theory, measurement operators at time-like separation from a given space-like hyperplane at time $t$ can in principal be expressed as a nontrivial function of the field and field momentum at time $t$, $\hat\phi(y)=\int[\hat\phi(t,\mathbf{x}')f_t(\mathbf{x}')+\hat\pi(t,\mathbf{x}')g_t(\mathbf{x}')]\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{x}'$, for two functions $f_t$ and $g_t$, which for a given theory are determined by the Lagrangian. Given many implicit assumptions, measuring the commutator $i[\hat\phi(t,\mathbf{x}),\hat\phi(y)]=-g_t(\mathbf{x})$ (because $[\hat\phi(t,\mathbf{x}),\hat\pi(t,\mathbf{y})]=i\delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})$) is equivalent to measuring $g_t(\mathbf{x})$. If we also measure $i[\hat\pi(t,\mathbf{x}),\hat\phi(y)]$, we can determine (or at least significantly constrain) the Lagrangian. *If we do not know the Lagrangian*, therefore, it would seem to be desirable to have an operational way to measure $i[\hat\phi(x),\hat\phi(y)]$ in order to *measure* the Lagrangian (instead of the usual approach of guessing the Lagrangian and seeing how close the consequent predictions are to the measurements; the haphazardness of this process is something of a crisis in HEP). I would welcome comments on this or an answer that takes this EDIT into account. Alternatively, an operational approach to *measuring* the Lagrangian would implicitly be a measurement, in principle, of $i[\hat\phi(x),\hat\phi(y)]$; is there such a thing?

Comment: great question -

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there will be any nontrivial reference about the hypothetical procedure because the misunderstanding seems to be hidden in the very question.

In a quantum field theory, $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]=0$ for spacelike separated $x,y$, due to the Lorentz invariance. This identity is an operator identity. So you're really asking what is the operational procedure to measure the value of an operator that is equal to zero. The right way to measure it is to be brave enough, to do nothing, and to say that the result is zero because it's the only eigenvalue of this operator.

If $x,y$ are timelike (or light-like, which is a marginal case) separated, the commutator is nonzero. But it's really meaningless to talk about the measurement of differently ordered operators at different times. Measurement in quantum mechanics is meant to be a measurement of a particular operator at a fixed time and when we consider a sequence of measurements, the ordering from the left to the right is correlated with their ordering in time because the measurements of operators at an increasing $t$ are acting on ket vectors one after another. That's why, for example, the $S$ matrix may be written as the time-ordered exponential of the integrated Hamiltonian.

Physically speaking, it only makes sense to place operators at points in the past to the right side of a product and operators from the future points to the left, assuming we are evaluating some evolution operator ready to act on ket vectors (for bra vectors it's the other way around, as seen by a simple Hermitian conjugation). Algebraically speaking, the oppositely ordered products are also meaningful but they don't correspond to any procedure.

One exception could be said: if you actually didn't want to measure the eigenvalue of the commutator but just the expectation value of the commutator of the elementary fields, a form of a propagator, then the "retarded commutator" (retarded means "with the theta-function imposing a right time-ordering") may be measured as a response function. One perturbs the operator at the initial time, and measures how much it changes the value of the operator at the final slice. Only the change of the expectation value is evaluated, and in this way, one may obtain the expectation value of the retarded commutator.

If $x,y$ were spacelike-separated but the commutator were nonzero, e.g. because the Lorentz symmetry would be broken, the commutator would still be equal to some particular operator that may be expressed as a functional of some "basic" operators. All Hermitian operators in a quantum mechanical theory are legitimate observables that may be measured. If you want me to describe a particular device and procedure to measure the value of the operator, what the gadget has to do, and so on, you must tell me exactly what theory you consider because devices to measure something do depend on the actual theory (i.e. its Hamiltonian).

These additional data you would have to add would of course describe a hypothetical situation because in our world, the commutator of spacelike-separated operators does vanish. A theory in which it wouldn't vanish would be a nonlocal one so the intuition in the Universe described by that other hypothetical theory would differ from the right intuition in our Universe, especially when it comes to things like the description of positions of objects (which is not a terribly useful concept if the theory is nonlocal, anyway).

You asked about the ways how to measure the value of a particular operator $0$ which was trivial. But maybe you wanted to ask a different question: how do we empirically prove that the commutator is zero, i.e. how do we prove this particular corollary of locality. Well, we could prove that the commutator is nonzero just like for the operators $x,p$ which appear in the uncertainty principle: the measurement of one of them inevitably disturbs the other. If the measurement of $\phi(x)$ disturbed the distibution of results obtained by measuring $\phi(y)$, the commutator would be nonzero.

However, to measure the actual value of the operator equal to the commutator is subtle. In general, the operator $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]$ commutes neither with $\phi(x)$ nor with $\phi(y)$. The case of $xp-px=i\hbar$ is kind of special because the commutator is a $c$-number. Because the commutator is a completely independent operator from $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$, its measurement procedure is of course completely independent from the measurement of $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$. In particular, if we want to measure $i(xp-px)$, the right way is once again to do nothing because the right value is always $-\hbar$.

That's another important misconception that is implicitly contained in your question. You seem to believe that the measurement of the commutator or product of several operators may be obtained by measurements of the individual factors in the commutator or the product. But this is not true at all. Take a simple example of $-i[J_x,J_y]/\hbar$. How do you measure the value of this operator equal to the commutator? Measuring $J_x$ and $J_y$ won't be any useful because the commutator is actually equal to $J_z$, the third and completely independent component! The classical observable corresponding to the commutator is *not* a function of the observables appearing in the commutator! In general, it's a completely different operator that may only be measured by a completely different procedure.

There's one more thing you may wanted to address: the situation in which $x,y$ are equal or very close to each other so that some nonzero term may arise from the delta-function-like commutator (or perhaps from some quantum loop corrections or renormalization, as seen in the effective action, etc.). Linking fields to actual apparata is always subtle because the identity of the fields in a field theory (or any theory) is only given up to field redefinitions (which may be nonlocal), and so on. So without having a particular convention about what you mean by the fields, which also implies that you may exactly calculate what the commutator is, it is meaningless to ask about such subtle questions. When you talk about $\phi(x)$, you have to use some particular scheme of conventions etc. so you're no longer talking about operationally doable things. If you want an operational answer, you need to formulate the question operationally as well.

At any rate, even in this case of a nonzero commutator from nearby $x,y$, the main points of the text above still hold. The measurement of the commutator is completely independent from the measurement of the operators whose commutator is being computed. And if the commutator is a $c$-number (which is always the case e.g. when there are only non-derivative interactions), the measurement procedure is to do "nothing".

Last comment. It also seems to me that you have a wrong idea about the actual value of the commutator in common interacting QFTs. In the Standard Model, all renormalizable interaction terms are non-derivative – they are polynomial of the fields but don't depend on the field derivatives. So if you compute the canonical momenta as the derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to the time-derivatives of the fields, the interaction terms will contribute nothing at all (because there are no time derivatives in the interaction Lagrangian)! So the equal-time commutators in the Standard Model are exactly the same as they are in the non-interacting limit of the Standard Model.

The timelike-separated (non-equal-time) commutators are affected by the interactions, of course, but the products that are not properly time-ordered don't correspond to any operational procedure.

Comment: That's the first time I've come up against Luboš full force, I think. I don't understand how it can be that "it's really meaningless to talk about the measurement of differently ordered operators at different times", given that HEP is about signals that change over time, which are then subjected to various signal analysis algorithms (albeit *ad hoc* ways are used to extract event timings from time-varying CCD currents, etc.). "Measurement in quantum mechanics is meant to be a measurement of a particular operator at a fixed time": so QM cannot model measurements at different times?

Comment: Dear Peter, "so QM cannot model measurements at different times?" It can. One can measure operators at arbitrary times, but one may only do so chronologically. One first measures the operator at an earlier time and then he measures another operator at a later time. The earlier operator acts on the ket as the first one, so it's on the right side, and the later operator acts later, so it's on the left side of the product. It makes no sense to ask how you make the two measurements in the opposite order. The order of the measurements is unambiguously determined by the ordering of arguments $t_i$.

Comment: You suggest in your last paragraph that I "believe that the measurement of the commutator or product of several operators may be obtained by measurements of the individual factors in the commutator or the product." I take my "in an interacting QFT [the commutator] may presumably be an observable independent of $\hat\phi(x)$ and $\hat\phi(y)$" to say otherwise.

Comment: At any rate, the main problem with your question is that you seem to assume that the measurement of a product of operators or commutator of operators may be reduced to the measurement of the individual operators, and some manipulation with the results. But this ain't the case because the operators equal to the commutators are not functions of the original operators in the classical sense. To measure the commutator, one has to do a totally different measurement that usually has nothing to do with the measurements of the observables appearing in the commutator.

Comment: Except that time-ordering makes the algebra of operators a commutative algebra (and not a $C^\star$-algebra unless we also introduce anti-time-ordering).

Comment: Dear Peter, concerning your "i take my... to say otherwise", it is also incorrect. I've added an explanation of it to the answer, too. The equal-time commutators in QFTs such as the Standard Model are completely unaffected by the interactions. The interaction terms add zero to the equal-time commutators because the renormalizable interactions in the Standard Model are non-derivative terms, which therefore don't change the formulae for the canonical momenta at all. So you're wrong that the interactions change anything.

Comment: "To measure the commutator, one has to do a totally different measurement that usually has nothing to do with the measurements of the observables appearing in the commutator." Right! Yes! And that's my question! What is that measurement, that is of neither the field nor its momentum?

Comment: Dear Peter, I think that I have answered your question about thrice already. The commutators of two operators are *always* some functionals of the "basic operators" such as the fields and their velocities (or canonical momenta); there is nothing "third" they may depend on. And in fact, the equal-time commutators between any operators in SM-like QFTs are completely identical to the commutators you get in the free theories where you just drop the interaction Hamiltonian. There is nothing nontrivial waiting in this evaluation.

Comment: Apologies if I am wrong but you may be misunderstanding how the commutators are determined in the process of quantization. For Lagrangians that depend at most at first derivatives, one writes some coordinates - spanning a configuration space - and their velocity. They fully specify the initial conditions. The canonical momenta are $\partial {\mathcal L}/ \partial (\partial_t x_i)$. The $[x,x]$ and $[p,p]$ commutators vanish while $[x_i,p_j]=i\hbar \delta_{ij}$. These rules are true even for interacting QFTs.

Comment: If you had a QFT without an explicit Lagrangian, like e.g. 2-dimensional model's minimal CFTs, then one couldn't evaluate the commutators by any methods based on the classical limit. But there would still be quantum operator formulae that determine the commutators of operators in terms of some other operators from the full basis of possible local fields. Those would be encoded in the OPEs.

Comment: "Except that time-ordering makes the algebra of operators a commutative algebra (and not a C⋆-algebra unless we also introduce anti-time-ordering)." - A commutator with time-ordering inside is really meaningless; I am not defending anything of the sort. I am just saying that if there is a process that does something with $X(Monday)$ and with $Y(Tuesday)$, then $X$ will be manipulated with one day ahead of $Y$, and if the manipulations are expressed as measurements or operations done with a ket vector, $X$ will be inevitably on the right side from $Y$.

Comment: The commutator of $X(Monday)$ and $Y(Tuesday)$ is nonzero - you don't really need quantum field theory to discuss these things, any QM theory with time is enough - but it doesn't correspond to any operation done with simple fields located on Monday and Tuesday slices. Moreover, if you talk about operators $X(t)$ for all $t$, they're not really independent from one another. By the Heisenberg dynamical equations, operators at one moment are functionals of operators at any other moment. There are many ways to measure them by procedures at various times one may choose.

Comment: "Measurement in quantum mechanics is meant to be a measurement of a particular operator at a fixed time" Practically, is there a measurement other than a yes/no observation, which is not a time average?

Comment: "operators at one moment are functionals of operators at any other moment" -- right, that's an answer, albeit encoded, that is a fundamental aspect of how QM is structured, in terms of the classical non-relativistic concept of a phase space. It leaves quite a few questions that seem very delicate, but thanks Luboš. +1 for the comments.

Comment: @Nick, I think your comment is *a propos*. Even yes/no answers are the result of (sometimes elaborate) signal conditioning, often as software triggers, but equally often in hardware. It is often critical that yes/no answers are reported together with the time at which the device signal went from no to yes, so that whether space-like separated device state transitions are temporally coincident can be determined. Much more could be said, of course.